# If I install a package from a previous version manually, will it be replaced with the newest version corresponding to my current release?

Tags: package-management

I tried installing VirtualBox on Wily Werewolf, and I couldn't install it because a dependency is missing. The package in question is "libvpx1".

I looked it up, and it seems it was removed:
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/wily/amd64/libvpx1

My question is, if I install that package from a Vivid Vervet source manually, will it update on it's own when the package is "returned" to the Wily source?

Answer (score 3):

> My question is, if I install that package from a Vivid Vervet source manually, will it update on it's own when the package is "returned" to the Wily source?

No because it was superseded by [libvpx2](http://packages.ubuntu.com/wily/libvpx2), which means it's unlikely that libvpx1 will return to the repositories.

You would need to install the VBox package regardless of the missing dependency (`dpkg -i --ignore-depends=libvpx1`), edit the dependency inside the package or wait for VBox developers to release an updated version of the package (or install the vivid deb and carry cruft around in your wily install).

I assume that this package is only required for recording a VM session (it's a video codec) so even if libvpx2 turns out to be incompatible basic functionality should work.

Related question: [Dependency errors when trying to install VirtualBox 5.0 on 15.10](https://askubuntu.com/q/696870/40581)