# Dependency errors when trying to install VirtualBox 5.0 on 15.10

Tags: apt, software-installation, virtualbox, dependencies, 15.10

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18 and I am trying to install VirtualBox 5.0 on my system, I have followed all the instructions in the `Debian-based Linux distributions` installation section [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads), however when I now try to actually install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-5.0
```

I get this output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 virtualbox-5.0 : Depends: libvpx1 (>= 1.0.0) but it is not installable
                  Recommends: libsdl-ttf2.0-0 but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: dkms but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

And I have tried running:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

But it says that there is nothing to upgrade or install.

So what do I do? I really need to install VirtualBox 5.0 but I seem unable to.

**Information Update:**

`apt-cache policy virtualbox-5.0 libvpx1` outputs:

```
virtualbox-5.0:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 5.0.10-104061~Ubuntu~trusty
  Version table:
     5.0.10-104061~Ubuntu~trusty 0
        500 http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/ vivid/contrib amd64 Packages
libvpx1:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
```

Comment: @ParanoidPanda You could try changing `vivid` to `wily` in your `/etc/apt/sources.list` for the entry for VirtualBox, more a more likely to be good solution would be to download the .deb file for wily from [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads) directly, and remove the PPA from your software sources.

Comment: Related question: http://askubuntu.com/q/688330/40581

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You use the repository for Vivid and the VirtualBox package in this repository depends on `libvpx1` which is available for Vivid but not for Wily.

As you are using Wily change the repository:

```
sudo sed -i 's/vivid/wily/' /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-5.0
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm pretty sure that it will work.

```
wget http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libv/libvpx/libvpx1_1.1.0-1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libvpx1_1.1.0-1_amd64.deb
wget http://ftp.cn.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libp/libpng/libpng12-0_1.2.49-1+deb7u2_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libpng12-0_1.2.49-1+deb7u2_amd64.deb
```

If `sudo apt-get install virtualbox-5.0` says that no installation for VirtualBox 5, download the installation file from [this link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2BGAPbTu7vhSUs0dkN5WXcyWXc/view)

Comment: this worked for me

Answer (score 1):

This should no longer be a problem, I had this problem only when adding the custom ppa, but the regular ubuntu version (5.0.14) install perfectly fine without other ppa's

"sudo apt-get install virtualbox"